# How to display PHP page from another server on an html without iFrame?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, iframe

I have the following iFrame HTML:

```
<html>
<iframe src="page.php" id="ifrm" height = 100%  width = 100% ></iframe>
</table>
</html>
```

I use it to display PHP inside an html page.

However, iframes are giving me a very hard time. Is there any other solution without using an iFrame?

What i Need basically is for the HTML page to display the php page without changing the browser url.

BTW: Both pages are on different servers.

Thx!

Comment: Depending on what the PHP script is doing, this won't work.

Comment: You mean that iFrame is the only solution to this?

Comment: No, its not what I want to say. There are some other solutions. I want to say that depending on what the page is doing you want to include, you can't use the functions of this page. So, you can display it, but may userinputs won't bring you the result you want.

Comment: Have you considered using an ajax call? You could then load the page manually with Javascript...

Comment: What's that `</table>` closing tag doing there?

Comment: If you can't use PHP, then your next option is an AJAX call; however, that usually will not work _Cross Site_. Looks like you're running out of options. I would try placing the '<iframe>' in the body of a correctly formatted HTML5 document, and persevere with it.

Answer (score 1):

You could try just reading the file in with `file_get_contents`, and then print it:

```
<?php
    $sContent =  file_get_contents('page.php'); //Replace 'page.php' with the full URI to the pages you want to show
    print ($sContent);
?>
```

This will work with most server setups, although not always.

Comment: Does not work... it's basically an html page, not a PHP. I need a solution somehow with HTML if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function file_get_contents('http://urlforsite.com/page')

```
$externalWebsite = 'http://externalsite.com/page';
$externalContent = file_get_contents($externalWebsite);
echo $externalContent;
```